# Xcode 10.2 compilation issues FirebaseCore

Tags: firebase, cocoapods, crashlytics, xcode10.2

Just updated to Xcode 10.2 and now our project won't compile. We're using FirebaseCore (via cocoa pods). Any idea what's going on?

```
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-bzgjsblgwdygzrcgpkzfblperpwl/Build/Products/Debug/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.framework/PrivateHeaders':
1) Target 'FirebaseCore' (project 'Pods') has symlink command from '/Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-bzgjsblgwdygzrcgpkzfblperpwl/Build/Products/Debug/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.framework/PrivateHeaders' to 'Versions/Current/PrivateHeaders'
2) Target 'FirebaseCore' (project 'Pods') has symlink command from '/Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-bzgjsblgwdygzrcgpkzfblperpwl/Build/Products/Debug/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.framework/PrivateHeaders' to 'Versions/Current/PrivateHeaders'
```

There are hundreds of these errors showing up.

```
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-bzgjsblgwdygzrcgpkzfblperpwl/Build/Products/Debug/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities.framework':
1) Target 'GoogleUtilities' (project 'Pods') has create directory command with output '/Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-bzgjsblgwdygzrcgpkzfblperpwl/Build/Products/Debug/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities.framework'
2) Target 'GoogleUtilities' (project 'Pods') has create directory command with output '/Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-bzgjsblgwdygzrcgpkzfblperpwl/Build/Products/Debug/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities.framework'
```

Any idea what needs to be done?